# Remove .php etension and add trailing slash with URL slug

Tags: .htaccess

We are trying to remove .php extension and add trailing slash with get method thru .htaccess by following the code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+)/?$ products.php?url_slug=$1 [END]
```

We are trying the product page to work with and without url_slug.

https://domainname/products/ - its working

https://domainname/products/url_slug/ - it shows 404

Please help Thanks in advance

Comment: Your current second rule with pattern `^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$` matches `products/url_slug/`, so the new URL from that point on will be `https://domainname/products/url_slug.php`. Probably not what you wanted to happen.

Comment: The partial overlap between `products/` and `products.php` can also be problematic, if `MultiViews` is enabled.

Comment: but we have a folder structure URL like https://domainname/folder/file so i have mentioned RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php

Comment: This rule gets applied in any case, whether a `folder/file.php` actually exists or not. A `RewriteCond` only ever applies to the rule immediately following it. You need to repeat your condition before that second rule, if you want it to apply to that one as well.

Comment: Thank you it works fine now actually, I have repeated the condition for the second one as well